# Fail to connect to a remote SQL server with SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm trying to connect to a remote database with SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. I got the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Erreur : 53)

[image]

I think that I have wrong with my config:

[image]

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: ping the server machine to check whether it is running..

Comment: @Kumar, ping will not solve this problem. The machine may respond but the port may block outgoing connections.

KALLEL, are you using the machine name or the IP address? Are you connecting from inside the network or outside of the network? These type of issues could relate to tons of different causes. Please provide more information.

Comment: You may need to add an incoming firewall rule to open TCP port 1433  . Also make sure that SQL authentication is enabled (not just Windows Authentication).

Answer (score 1):

Steps to find out what the reason is:

1. Does the SQL server allow remote connections? Main settings SQL Server
2. Is TCP/IP enabled for client connections and listen on correct IP address / NIC?
3. Does the firewall on the server allow incoming traffic for the SQL Server port (default 1433)

It is normally one of the 3 points above.